# Custom transition using gif

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an app in which I need to transition to each side of a vehicle, using buttons. I would like to animate each transition, so that a gif plays that shows the vehicle turning from one side to another. My app can be found at the following github address: https://github.com/rileylloyd24/Engine-Master. Under Engine 131, you will see 2 buttons at the bottom. I would like each button to rotate the view left and right to the front and back of the truck, with gif animations. If there is a better way to go about doing this than a gif, please show me your ideas.

Comment: Can you formulate your question in a way I don't have to download your application to find out?

Comment: @Jano Unfortunately I can't post images yet, but I want to transition between 4 sides of a firetruck, but use a gif or something so it looks like the truck is rotating and not some random flipping animation.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use set of images,in place of gif.

```
-(void)animateButtonWithTimer:(float)timer{

self.btnRecordingIndicator.imageView.animationImages =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rec-on"],
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"rec-off"],
 nil];//add more image to animate
self.btnRecordingIndicator.imageView.animationDuration = timer; //whatever you want (in seconds)
[self.btnRecordingIndicator.imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Pictures or gifs seem like they would take up a lot of space, is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: its for small & simple animation.if you are using many image(like 40 or 100). then yes , it will take to much memory at run time. in this case you have some option(OpneGL,Cocos2D) link1 http://www.raywenderlich.com/32045/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-2-x link2 http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/

Comment: Wouldn't I want a 3D solution to rotate a vehicle? or would 2D suffice?

Comment: so how you want it to. can you show some screenshot. it will help in what level of animation you are trying, & what will be best suitable way to do this.